# Receive-Job not returning same type as calling the script block without a Job

Tags: .net, powershell, parallel-processing, f#, jobs

I am loading an F# dll that defines certain types in a powershell script, in order to create a web request with a body to send it to a web service made in F#. One of those types is the following:

```
type Resource =
| VM of VMResource
| Unit of UnitResource
```

With

```
type VMResource = {
    ComputerName: string
    Ip: string
    Attributes: string[]
}

type UnitResource = {
    UnitName: string
    Ip: string
    Username: string
    Password: string
    Attributes: string[]
}
```

When I run the following small powershell snippet, the request's response is actually of type `GetResourcesResponse` (which is a record type containing an Array of `Resource`), which is what I want:

```
Add-Type -Path "pathtomydll.dll"

$fullRequestUrl = "http://localhost:2121/Resources/Get"
$body = "{`"Id`":`"Test`",`"RequestedResources`":[{`"ResourceType`":{`"Case`":`"VM`"},`"Attributes`":[`"A1`",`"A2`"]},{`"ResourceType`":{`"Case`":`"Unit`"},`"Attributes`":[]}]}"

$resp = Invoke-WebRequest $fullRequestUrl -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
$obj = [ServerProtocolTypes+GetResourcesResponse]::FromJson($resp)
$obj.GetType() # GetResourcesResponse
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the same code in a Job, I get a PSObject type with a property which is an Array of `string` representation of my `Resource` type (for example: `ResourceTypes+Resource+VM`), which doesn't contain any information about the `VMResource` or `UnitResource`:

```
Add-Type -Path "pathtomydll.dll"

$fullRequestUrl = "http://localhost:2121/Resources/Get"
$body = "{`"Id`":`"Test`",`"RequestedResources`":[{`"ResourceType`":{`"Case`":`"VM`"},`"Attributes`":[`"A1`",`"A2`"]},{`"ResourceType`":{`"Case`":`"Unit`"},`"Attributes`":[]}]}"

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($url, $reqBody) Add-Type -Path "pathtomydll.dll"; $resp = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Post -Body $reqBody -ContentType "application/json"; return [ServerProtocolTypes+GetResourcesResponse]::FromJson($resp) } -ArgumentList ($fullRequestUrl, $body)
Wait-Job $job
$obj = Receive-Job $job
$obj.GetType() # PSObject
```

In this case, `$obj` is an array of string, with one entry being `ResourceTypes+Resource+VM` and the other being `ResourceTypes+Resource+Unit`.

Is there any way for me to get back my `GetResourcesResponse` object back from the Job instead of a `PSObject` that contains an array of `string`?

Comment: I think the problem is that output from Jobs is serialized when it's returned. You can run parallel processes and retain the native object types by using runspaces instead of jobs.

Comment: After a short research, I have found that this is indeed probably the cause (from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382728/passing-native-object-to-background-jobs)). You could put that as an answer, and will select it as the good answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Done.  Hope you get it sorted out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments:

I think the problem is that output from Jobs is serialized when it's returned. You can run parallel processes and retain the native object types by using runspaces instead of jobs.